# How to create this makefile? Sources in subdirectories, separate output path, linking objects in subdirectories

Tags: makefile

Is there a way to create a makefile that does this?
I gave up after trying to follow the docs and lots of trial and error so I'll just post a description of what the makefile should do.

general directory structure:

```
src/ - contains c source files in various subdirectories (written manually by maintainer)
inc/ - contains h header files in subdirectories matching src (written manually by maintainer)
obj/ - contains o header files in subdirectories matching src (autogenerated by a make call)
bin/ - should contain binary (autogenerated by a make call)
makefile
```

so for example at a given point of time the project might look like

```
src/
    main.c
    sub1/
        other1.c
        other2.c
    sub2/
        sub3/
            other3.c
inc/
    sub1/
        other1.h
        other2.h
    sub2/
        sub3/
            other3.h
obj/
    main.o
    sub1/
        other1.o
        other2.o
    sub2/
        sub3/
            other3.o
bin/
    release
makefile
```

(probably not relevant: Note that main doesn't have a header file but most likely every other c file will have a matching h file.)

I want to be able to call make, and have it:

- use gcc to recompile only changed c files into respective o files in obj/, generating missing subdirectories if needed.
  for example, from the above state, if I add a new subdirectory sub4 inside src/sub1/, and then create other4.c inside src/sub1/sub4/, I would like make to generate sub4 inside obj/sub1/ and then generate other4.o inside obj/sub1/sub4/
- create a binary at bin/release by linking all object files (from all subdirectories in obj/)
- I don't want to have to change the makefile each time I add directories in src
- I don't want to manually have to create directories in obj, the makefile should take care of it. if this is not possible, maybe have it rename all obj o files to a flat naming pattern? i.e. obj/sub2_sub3_other3.o instead of obj/sub2/sub3/other3.o (although this can cause issues)
- probably not relevant here, but the C files use include statements in this format:

```c
#include "sub2/sub3/other3.h"
```

so `-I./inc` would be included in the gcc call. Whereas the linker would receive inputs like `-s -O3`. I want to make sure those options (compiler options, linker options) are listed at the top of the makefile in variables (CFLAGS, LDFLAGS, etc) and not passed incorrectly to the targets.

is this even possible? if not, what's the closest possible?

Also, can this makefile be made to work on both POSIX systems and on Windows based systems? e.g. work the same on linux/gcc and win/mingw

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not the place to ask for someone else to design your entire build system.  You say you've done a lot of work but haven't succeeded; a better bet is to ask small, specific questions about issues you're having.  The short answer to your question is "yes everything you want to do is possible", with the caveat you won't be able to do it in portable makefiles so you'll need to commit to using GNU make on all your systems and there may be some annoying/unpleasant things in your makefile (but these won't be visible to users of your makefiles).

Comment: @MadScientist that's actually a useful reply, thanks. I was not sure if make supports certain things mainly related to handling subdirectories and path mapping or whether it has to be done by calling os commands, and your reply makes it clear that make does not have the built-in tools for this.

Comment: POSIX make has nothing.  GNU make has certain functions that can be used; see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Functions.html (the title says "for transforming text" but there are also functions like `wildcard` and `shell` which do more).  However, yes, you'll have to create directories, etc. yourself.

Comment: Got it, this is very useful, thanks for the link and for explaining.